# Dotnet Core - Getting "Parameter context of method .ctor is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I am getting the following warning:

> Parameter context of method .ctor is never used. Remove the parameter
>   or use it in the method body.

On the following line:

```
public void DATAInitialiseStates(DATAContext context)
```

In the following Code:

```
using JobsLedger.DATA;
using JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES;
using JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.DATA.Initialisations.Interfaces;
using JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.SUBURB.Initialisations;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace JobsLedger.INITIALISATION.DATA.Initialisations
{
    public class DATAStateInitialiser : IDATAStateInitialiser
    {

        public void DATAInitialiseStates(DATAContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.States.Any())
            {
                return;     //DB table data already created.
            }

            var baseStateInitialiser = new BaseStateInitialiser();
            var BaseStateList = baseStateInitialiser.BaseStateList();

            for (int i = 0; i < BaseStateList.Length; i++)
            {
                var state = new State
                {
                    StateName = BaseStateList[i].StateName,
                    StateShortName = BaseStateList[i].StateShortName
                };

                context.States.Add(state);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the parameter so I don't understand why I am getting it and... whats the best way to avoid this without suppressing the error.. or do I have to in this instance..

Comment: I think the warning is actually about a line other than the one you posted.

Comment: Happy to be corrected.. which one?

Comment: I can't say for sure based on what you posted, but given the warning says it's for `.ctor` and the method you posted isn't the constructor (oddly, I don't see a constructor), I'm inclined to say that it's not that one.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? There seems to have been a potentially related issue with the Roslyn analyzer at one point in time. Searching for the error message brought up [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1713) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1691), among others.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I just installed the Roslyn Analyser... :(

Comment: Where is the code about '.ctor'? Besides, If it is just a warning, you can ignore it. As usual, it will not affect the program.

Comment: Sure.. I believe the .ctor refers to constructor.. Its saying that the constructor has a var that isnt used but it clearly is.. anyway thats my guess so far... and yes its a warning.. so for now ignore it